# 0 results from COUNT tSQL via PHP

Tags: php, excel, t-sql

I can run these queries:

```
"SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = 'myusername' and date >= '2014 03 01 00:00:00' and page LIKE '%Order%'"
```

in the Microsoft SQL management studio and I get the results I expect, numbers in the 60's but when I run this code and generate an excel document via PHP it comes back with all 0's

```
<?php
include 'sqlconn.php';

$filename = "userAccessReport.xls";
$reportFile = fopen("somdirectory/".$filename, "w"); 


fwrite($reportFile,"<table><tr><td>username</td><td>visits this month ".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00</td><td>page</td></tr>");

$users = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT uname FROM usepeeps");
while (odbc_fetch_array($users))
{

    $username=odbc_result($users,'uname');        

    fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td>".$username."</td><td></td><td></td></tr>");

    $orderWell = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = '".$username."' and date >= '".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00' and page LIKE '%Order%'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($orderWell)){fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td></td><td>".odbc_result($orderWell,'userNum')."-</td><td>Order Well</td></tr>");}

    $receipts = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = '".$username."' and date >= '".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00' and page LIKE '%Receipt%'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($receipts)){fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td></td><td>".odbc_result($receipts,'userNum')."-</td><td>Receipts</td></tr>");}

    $inventory = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = '".$username."' and date >= '".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00' and page LIKE '%Inventory%'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($inventory)){fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td></td><td>".odbc_result($inventory,'userNum')."-</td><td>Inventory</td></tr>");}

    $einv = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = '".$username."' and date >= '".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00' and pageLIKE '%Invoicing%'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($einv)){fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td></td><td>".odbc_result($einv,'userNum')."-</td><td>E-Invoicing</td></tr>");}

    $brdroom = odbc_exec($live, "SELECT COUNT(uname) as userNum FROM loginhistory WHERE user = '".$username."' and date >= '".date("Y m")." 01 00:00:00' and page LIKE '%Boardroom%'");
    while(odbc_fetch_array($brdroom)){fwrite($reportFile,"<tr><td></td><td>".odbc_result($brdroom,'userNum')."-</td><td>Boardroom Booking</td></tr>");}

}

fwrite($reportFile,"</table>");
fclose($reportFile);
echo "/dev/tempfiles/" . $filename;
```

Comment: when I say 0 results I suppose thats wrong it generates a result set because the while loop executes, but the counters `userNum` is 0

Comment: its a typo in the 4th query `... and pageLIKE '%Invoicing%'");`

Answer (score 0):

You never capture the results from your `fetch` calls, effectively losing ALL of the results. You should have something more like:

```
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($einv)) {
     echo $row['userNum'];
}
```

Since your `fetch_array()` call fetches and LOSES the **ONE** row of result data, there's nothing left for `odbc_result()` to work with.

Comment: craaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaap if this is true I've done this in a LOT of other places and am losing the first row each time? oh no

I don't even know how I got off track, this is the way I used to do it... I must have copied some code somewhere and kept referencing that code for all my query results...

Comment: I made the change you suggested and no difference in the result

Comment: did you change ALL of your while() loops? You've got the same thing for fetching the username as well.

Comment: I did, I changed every `while()` and replaced every single `odbc_result()` to `$row[]` the excel file generates and looks exactly the same as the one I was generating before

Comment: I know the `$row = odbc_fetch_array()` code is working because its printing the usernames where it should be

lowacc  
 0 Order Well
 0 Receipts
 0 Inventory
 0 Boardroom Booking

Comment: and actually now that I revert back to my original code I see that I have not lost any usernames from my database doing my way, so I think maybe your answer is not exactly what I am looking for, but I appreciate the help, sometimes an extra set of eyes is all you need